# Opening WordPress on wordpress.example.com, while the webpage is at example.com

Tags: login, subdomains, apache

Is it possible to set up WordPress so that you log on on a subdomain while the webpage edited is the main domain? And if yes, how?
I know about home and site URL, but all the examples to those were in the form of Site URL: example.com, Home URL: example.com/wp-admin

I want to set up WordPress on an Ubuntu VPS with LAMP.

Comment: In theory yes. But fiddling with URLs within WordPress can be tedious and many things can go wrong. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: It's just a personal challenge. And I think it's looks neater and cleaner.